# Android: NotificationCompat.MediaStyle action buttons don't do anything

Tags: android, android-mediasession, mediabrowserservicecompat, android-notification.mediastyle

I've got a simple Android app containing one `Activity` and a `Service` that derives from `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`. I've successfully gotten it set up to play audio from my main activity by using `MediaBrowserCompat` and `MediaControllerCompat`. It can even play and pause the audio from my Bluetooth headphones. All good.

My challenge concerns the `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` notification that appears on the lock screen and in the notifications tray. The notification appears properly. However, when I add buttons using `addAction()` and `MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent`, they don't do anything. If I instead add a dummy PendingIntent that just launches my main activity, that works fine.

Here's my code to generate the notification (apologies, this is C# running in Xamarin, so the casing and names will be slightly different from what you might expect). This is inside my service class.

```
var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .SetVisibility(NotificationCompat.VisibilityPublic)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
    .SetContentTitle("Title")
    .SetContentText("Content")
    .SetSubText("Subtext")
    .SetLargeIcon(icon)
    .SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.DarkOrange)

    .SetContentIntent(intent)
    .SetDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.BuildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ActionStop))

    .AddAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
        Resource.Drawable.ic_pause, "Pause",
        MediaButtonReceiver.BuildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ActionPause)))

    .SetStyle(new Android.Support.V4.Media.App.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
        .SetShowActionsInCompactView(0)
        .SetMediaSession(this.mediaSession.SessionToken)
        .SetShowCancelButton(true)
        .SetCancelButtonIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.BuildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ActionStop))
    );

this.StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());
```

Here's what I have looked at so far to try to solve this:

- When I start playback, I use `MediaSession.setActive(true)`
- Each time I start and stop playback, I set the appropriate actions in `PlaybackStateCompat`
- I have the session token set correctly.
- I do **not** have anything set up as a `MediaButtonReceiver` in my manifest, nor have I set anything up to handle `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON`, because I am targeting Android 5.0 and higher and using the `*Compat` classes, and my understanding is that that is no longer necessary.

I know that media button events are being routed properly to my app, since my Bluetooth headphone buttons work. I tried it in my car and it works there too. **It's just the buttons in the notification that won't work.** I'm expecting them to generate calls to the appropriate methods of `MediaSessionCompat.Callback`. Is this incorrect? What am I doing wrong here?

I would be grateful for any pointers.

---

**UPDATE:**
I got it working. I needed to add the following inside the `<application>` node of the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

...and the following inside the node of the Service that implements `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I'm still a little confused about *why* this was necessary, since button presses from my Bluetooth headphones and car infotainment system were routed to the app just fine. More importantly, Google [says](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver#buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(android.content.Context,%20long)):

> If you already have a `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` in your app,
>   `MediaButtonReceiver` will deliver the received key events to the
>   `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` by default. You can handle them in your
>   `MediaSessionCompat.Callback`.

They gave this as an *alternative* to the option "Service Handling ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON," so I took that to mean I didn't need to do anything more with my manifest. If anyone could enlighten me here, I would appreciate it.

But, for what it's worth, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have not set up the actions. Look the code below, it show how to bind the buttons with an intent. Please modify it for android O devices which require a channel.

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;

/**
 * Keeps track of a notification and updates it automatically for a given MediaSession. This is
 * required so that the music service don't get killed during playback.
 */
public class MediaNotificationManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 412;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    private static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.example.android.musicplayercodelab.pause";
    private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.android.musicplayercodelab.play";
    private static final String ACTION_NEXT = "com.example.android.musicplayercodelab.next";
    private static final String ACTION_PREV = "com.example.android.musicplayercodelab.prev";

    private final MusicService mService;

    private final NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    private final NotificationCompat.Action mPlayAction;
    private final NotificationCompat.Action mPauseAction;
    private final NotificationCompat.Action mNextAction;
    private final NotificationCompat.Action mPrevAction;

    private boolean mStarted;

    public MediaNotificationManager(MusicService service) {
        mService = service;

        String pkg = mService.getPackageName();
        PendingIntent playIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        mService,
                        REQUEST_CODE,
                        new Intent(ACTION_PLAY).setPackage(pkg),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent pauseIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        mService,
                        REQUEST_CODE,
                        new Intent(ACTION_PAUSE).setPackage(pkg),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent nextIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        mService,
                        REQUEST_CODE,
                        new Intent(ACTION_NEXT).setPackage(pkg),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent prevIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        mService,
                        REQUEST_CODE,
                        new Intent(ACTION_PREV).setPackage(pkg),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        mPlayAction =
                new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_24dp,
                        mService.getString(R.string.label_play),
                        playIntent);
        mPauseAction =
                new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_pause_white_24dp,
                        mService.getString(R.string.label_pause),
                        pauseIntent);
        mNextAction =
                new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_skip_next_white_24dp,
                        mService.getString(R.string.label_next),
                        nextIntent);
        mPrevAction =
                new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_white_24dp,
                        mService.getString(R.string.label_previous),
                        prevIntent);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_NEXT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_PLAY);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_PREV);

        mService.registerReceiver(this, filter);

        mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) mService.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Cancel all notifications to handle the case where the Service was killed and
        // restarted by the system.
        mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case ACTION_PAUSE:
                mService.mCallback.onPause();
                break;
            case ACTION_PLAY:
                mService.mCallback.onPlay();
                break;
            case ACTION_NEXT:
                mService.mCallback.onSkipToNext();
                break;
            case ACTION_PREV:
                mService.mCallback.onSkipToPrevious();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void update(
            MediaMetadataCompat metadata,
            PlaybackStateCompat state,
            MediaSessionCompat.Token token) {
        if (state == null
                || state.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED
                || state.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_NONE) {
            mService.stopForeground(true);
            try {
                mService.unregisterReceiver(this);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                // ignore receiver not registered
            }
            mService.stopSelf();
            return;
        }
        if (metadata == null) {
            return;
        }
        boolean isPlaying = state.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING;
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mService);
        MediaDescriptionCompat description = metadata.getDescription();

        notificationBuilder
                .setStyle(
                        new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                                .setMediaSession(token)
                                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
                .setColor(
                        mService.getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_bg))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentIntent(createContentIntent())
                .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
                .setContentText(description.getSubtitle())
                .setLargeIcon(MusicLibrary.getAlbumBitmap(mService, description.getMediaId()))
                .setOngoing(isPlaying)
                .setWhen(isPlaying ? System.currentTimeMillis() - state.getPosition() : 0)
                .setShowWhen(isPlaying)
                .setUsesChronometer(isPlaying);

        // If skip to next action is enabled
        if ((state.getActions() & PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS) != 0) {
            notificationBuilder.addAction(mPrevAction);
        }

        notificationBuilder.addAction(isPlaying ? mPauseAction : mPlayAction);

        // If skip to prev action is enabled
        if ((state.getActions() & PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT) != 0) {
            notificationBuilder.addAction(mNextAction);
        }

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

        if (isPlaying && !mStarted) {
            mService.startService(new Intent(mService.getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class));
            mService.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
            mStarted = true;
        } else {
            if (!isPlaying) {
                mService.stopForeground(false);
                mStarted = false;
            }
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }
    }

    private PendingIntent createContentIntent() {
        Intent openUI = new Intent(mService, MusicPlayerActivity.class);
        openUI.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mService, REQUEST_CODE, openUI, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    }
}
```